# Datamapper "first" method is querying the whole relation

Tags: sql, ruby, performance, orm, datamapper

I'm using Datamapper 1.0 with sinatra and sqlite3 as backend.

I have some devices, which have multiple locations, and I usually only want the latest location of a device. The problem is that the generated SQL for the above line will query all locations for the device not just the latest one (and a device can have 10-20k locations). This is clearly not optimal, so I'm asking: am I doing something wrong? Or datamapper works this way and I have to resort back to plain SQL? Is there a better workaround?

I have the following data schema:

```
class Location
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :lat, Integer
  property :lon, Integer
  property :time, Time
  belongs_to :device
end

class Device
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  has n, :locations

  def lat # and lon
    locations.first(:order => [:time.desc]).lat
  end
end
```

Here a call to `d.first.lat` (where `d` is a `Device` acquired using `d = Devices.all`) will result in a query of all the locations, instead of only the first matching one.

I have only these two models, and the querying is simple too:

- In controller: `@devices = Device.all`
- In view: `@devices.each { |d| d.lat }`
- And in model: `def lat; locations.first.lat; end`

Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a working `Location` and `Device` class? For instance, the classes above are missing the `DataMapper::Resource` includes line, and missing primary keys.

Furthermore, how are you querying the `Device`, e.g. `d = Device.first` or `d = Device.all`?

Comment: Added the include line, the primary keys and how the querying is done.

Comment: You may be getting bitten by Strategic Eager Loading (SEL). Try doing @devices = Device.to_a to return an Array, then I *think* the code should work as you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the trick is to use a has 1 assocation

```
class Device
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  has n, :locations # You probably want :order => [:time.desc] here too
  has 1, :latest_location, :class_name => Location, :order => [:time.desc]

  def lat
    latest_location.lat
  end
end
```